# Reading columns from data file in fortran

Tags: format, fortran

I wrote the following block to read from an external data file:

```
     open(unit=338,file='bounnodes.dat',form='formatted') 
      DO I=1,NQBOUN
         DO J=1,NUMBOUNNODES(I)
            read(338,2001) NODEBOUN(i,j)
            write(6,*) 'BOUNDARY NODES',  NODEBOUN(i,j)
         ENDDO
       ENDDO
     2001
     FORMAT(32I5)
```

As far as I understood, this should read a 2 x 32 array from `bounnodes.dat`.
However, I get an error `end-of-file` during read and it prints the first column.

I tried to read a 32 x 2 array using the same code, and it reads 32 elements of the first column, but outputs `0s` for the next column.

Can you please explain what is happening? Is my formatting wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Every read statement in Fortran advances to the next record. This means a new line in normal text files. Try this:

```
   DO I=1,NQBOUN
     DO J=1,NUMBOUNNODES(I)
        read(338,2001,advance='no') NODEBOUN(i,j)
        write(*,*) 'BOUNDARY NODES',  NODEBOUN(i,j)
     ENDDO
     read(338,*)
   ENDDO
```

where NQBOUN is number of rows and NUMBOUNNODES(I) is number of columns in a row. (I have allway problems, what is 32x2 vs. 2x32)

You can make it even shorter, using the implied do

```
   DO I=1,NQBOUN
        read(338,2001) ( NODEBOUN(i,j) , j=1,NUMBOUNNODES(I) )
        write(*,*) ( 'BOUNDARY NODES', NODEBOUN(i,j) , j=1,NUMBOUNNODES(I) )
   ENDDO
```

or even

```
   DO I=1,NQBOUN
        read(338,2001) NODEBOUN(i,:)
        write(*,*) 'BOUNDARY NODES',  NODEBOUN(i,1:NUMBOUNNODES(I))
   ENDDO
```

All of these use Fortran 90 features.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I also learned that the file is read row by row, so it is necessary to index the array into which we read the file accordingly.