# Reading Data Horizontally

Tags: file-io, fortran, gfortran

The following is a data set I am working with:

```
    2             19.000000E-01  4.246377E+24  9000.0        100.0  106.0  1400.0
    2.601629E+4   1E+24          2.232456E+2   0.100000E+00
    0.000000E+00  0.20000E+00    1.000000E+00  5.169046E+4
    0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00
```

I want to read the elements of this text data set from left to right using Gfortran. However, my code is reading it from top to bottom. In addition, it's not reading all of the elements. Is there any way I can make my GFortran code read from left to right and read all of the elements?

Here is my code:

```
  PROGRAM S1
  IMPLICIT NONE

  REAL :: col1
  REAL :: col2, col3
  REAL :: col4, col5
  REAL :: col6, col7
  INTEGER :: IOstatus=0



  open (unit = 1, file = "testing.txt", STATUS = "OLD")
  readloop: DO
  READ (1,*,IOSTAT=IOstatus) col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7
  IF (IOstatus /=0) EXIT
  WRITE (*, *) col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7
  END DO readloop
  END PROGRAM
```

Thanks. If there's any other information I can give, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Fortran reads records line-by-line (row-by-row). Reading column-by-column is not very simple.

When I run this, this is the output I get:

```
   2.00000000       1.89999998       4.24637708E+24   9000.00000       100.000000       106.000000       1400.00000
   26016.2891       1.00000001E+24   223.245605      0.100000001       0.00000000      0.200000003       1.00000000
```

Since Fortran reads row by row, it will try to read everything in the first row, then the second, and so on. In this case, the first iteration of the loop read seven items from the first row. The second iteration read four items from the second row and then three from the third row. The third iteration attempted to read the rest, but as there were no additional items to read, the `READ` failed and the loop exited.

To read columns will take some work. The first step is probably to make your column variables arrays. You may have to read records (lines/rows) and parse them yourself, or read items one at a time and manually sort them into columns.

Also, check out this post; it may offer some help: [Reading columns from data file in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623569/reading-columns-from-data-file-in-fortran)